# Is there any way to make a Chinese speech transcribed to written format?

Tags: mandarin, software, spoken, listening

Here is my situation: I have learned Mandarin mostly from reading news articles and chatting with friends, as well as reading a grammar book and memorizing vocabulary. That makes only my reading and writing skills improved, while my speaking and listening skills are practically useless.

So these days my friends started to make a speech on WeChat, instead of writing a message. However, in almost all cases I don't understand what they say. That makes me wonder if there is any way to transcribe the speech my friend made for me.

Is there any app or software, or otherwise any ways, to make the speech transcribed?

We use WeChat, for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WeChat could convert the voice accepted from others to text. By 长按 (touch and hold) on the voice, and select "转换为文字（仅普通话）" (for Android) or "转文字" (for iOS), you'll get the text showed under the voice.

Note that it works only for 普通话 (putonghua), and the language of WeChat (maybe the language of the system, depending on the settings of WeChat) needs to be set to 简体 (simplified Chinese).

Refer [here](http://www.uzzf.com/news/27142.html) for more screen captures.

Comment: Did you see 转换为文字? In my case (iOS) it is 转文字.

Comment: @Blaszard Yes I see that on Android. It seems different on Android and iOS. (Does that mean the version on iOS not only works with 普通话, but also other dialects? :) )